# Installing Unity desktop into Centos 7

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ubuntu-unity

I am very much familiar with Ubuntu's Unity desktop and my company uses Centos 7 for development which is not controlled by me.

Are there any manuals or wikipages that instructs about installing Ubuntu's unity desktop into Centos 7?

Comment: Have you tried using the Gnome desktop with CentOS 7?  What issues are you seeing with using Gnome that CentOS provides?  What issues are you seeing with installing Gnome? This page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface) describes how Unity is a shell for Gnome. and this Unix SE link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181503/how-to-install-desktop-environments-on-centos-7 has details on how to install Gnome.  Could you edit your question to provide more details on what you have tried and what errors you have encountered?  Thank you.